# If a fish had multiple pelvic fins, could some of these fins migrate up the body?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, anatomy

While the pelvic fins have been found in many places on fish, it always seems to be somewhere on the belly. Would this trait be conserved in a fish with many pairs of pelvic fins, or is it plausible that some of the fins might end up on the sides?

Comment: Yes, it it has happened a lot.  I just can't back up the answer.

Comment: Do you mean "sides" as in modern tetrapods, including humans? Remember tetrapods  evolved from fish.

Comment: Given the diversity of real world fish morphology what makes you think that this wouldn't be the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The fins could migrate to the long of the body but always in the ventral region**

Different fish species have pelvic fins in places which look strange compared with tetrapods.

[image]
The red lipped bat fish is one of them.

[image]

A frog fish as example too.

[image]

And the musdskipper.

All them have displaced their pelvic fin to more advanced positions practicaling staying in the same place as we think is the pectoral zone.

So if a fish would have more pelvic girdles and fins the most possible happening is that the fish migrate the fins to the long of its body to get multiple specializations for different works but to long of the ventral section of the body.

I don't know any case in which the fins could migrate upper in the body.